# How many edges could a cross-section of a polyhedron have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We know that the cross-section of a cube could have 3, 4, 5, or 6 edges. But there could be no more. This can be explained in many ways:

(1) The number of edges of a cross-section can't exceed the number of faces of the polyhedron.

(2) Consider the cube as a planar graph, if we divide the vertex set into two disjoint partitions, the maximal number of edges spanning between those sets is 6.

But both methods only offer a very rough estimate of the upper limit of the number of edges of the cross-section. Is there a more accurate way to calculate how many edges could a cross-section of a polyhedron have?

Comment: The upper bound is tight, in general.  I'll try to describe a situation where you can have the largest number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two cones which are joined along their bases (which are $2n$-sided polygons).  Now, adjust the vertices along the base so that they zig-zag when you look at the cones from the side (move the odd vertices towards one cone's vertex and the even ones in the other direction).  Now, a cut between the zig-zags will have as many sides as the original polyhedron.

Comment: it seems like you are describing the petrie polygon.